# Scroll able Arc Menu android

Tags: java, android, android-menu

we have got a requirement in our ongoing project where we need to show menu items in arc style at both upper space and lower space of the screen in reverse direction(will show you samples). i've tried to use some of the code from [the demo of ArcMenu used in Path android application](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu), but what i came up with is this:

[image: img1] [image: img2]

This is not what i want to achieve but something like menus in following images.

[image: img3]

I am trying to achieve this from last 4 to 5 days but not getting it right. if any one out there has done any research on such problem then please guide me.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello KunalK... do you find some solution please let me know now i m also  working on same task thanks

Answer (score 6):

Make ListView in Circular

Follow this **its working code**. Code is provided by **Samsung**

may be it will workfor your issues

http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples/Circle-Launcher

Comment: Wow quite nice of them ;)

Comment: this work only for vertical scrolling because the class CircleListView extends ListView, can you tell me the solution for horizontal scrolling ?

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a complicated task, especially since you want it to scroll while respecting its arc shape. There are probably no fixed answers for this, you'll have to manually create this type of interaction. Unless you have specific code examples of what you've tried and failed at, I don't think anyone can really help you here. Besides the technical difficulty, you could wonder if it is really a smart idea to have THAT many options in an already pretty unclear/overwhelming widget, that you can scroll to even more options. Maybe some design re-thinking is a better option.

Some examples though which could you get on the way would be here;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072692/a-circular-layout-with-scrollable-contents-in-it